# Probability of an event given a certain condition

Tags: probability

On a cold day $11\%$ of the people have a coughing and $7\%$ have a fever and $3\%$ have both.

So the probability that a random selected person is healthy is $82\%$. If a random selected person is sick, I think the probability of the person having a coughing **and** a fever is $\frac{3}{18}$. And the probability for a random selected person having a coughing **or** a fever but not both should be $12\%$.
Is that correct? I just relied on my intuition, what kind of formulas should I be using to guarantee right numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to check if your intuition is correct:
\begin{eqnarray}
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)
\\
P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} \quad \text{conditional probability}
\\
P(A \setminus B) = P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A \cap B) \quad \text{probability of set difference}
\end{eqnarray}